# Undeterminate number of fields

Tags: sql

I'm making a table that has an integer for a number of days programmed by the user. Let's imagine the user write that he wants 10 days.
I NEED to have a field for DAY1,DAY2,..,DAY10 to save an integer.

How do I make a table so save the integers from the Days?

Comment: create a table with columns "username" and "days" and store the data. don't create a table with day1, day2, day3,... thats a very bad design

Comment: but I need to store a number for each day. Like this: https://gyazo.com/d2c0298a8deb128854e56b1ac99ccfc9